# How to manipulate classes like (class1+class2)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've never Class declaration like .class1 + .class2{} .I need to manipulate `padding-top` attribute using Js.

**CSS**

```
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 150px;  
}
```

And here's what I tried in Js. I want to make that `padding top -150px`. I need to be able to change it dynamically. It doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

**JS**

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content"+".sticky");
  for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.paddingTop = -150 +"px";;
    myElements[i].style.sticky = -150 +"px";;
}
```

Comment: @Kobe can you give me an example in code please?

Comment: Your code would be more readable if you typed `"-150px"` instead of `-150 + "px"`, and `".content.sticky"` instead of `".content"+".sticky"`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `myElements[i].style.sticky = -150 +"px"` here?

Comment: are content and sticky classes on different components or content is child component of sticky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use no space to make the rule apply *only* if the element has *both* classes:

```css
.sticky.content {
  padding-top: 150px;  
}
```

As for JS, you would do the same:

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content.sticky");
```

---

If content is the direct child of sticky, use:

```
.sticky > .content
```

or if it just a child or grandchild, use

```
.sticky .content
```

If content is the next sibling of sticky, use:

```
.sticky + .content
```

Answer (score 1):

The `a + b` selector in the CSS meaning that the element `b` following the element `a` in the HTML DOM. If this is really what you want, than you have error in your JS in the line:

```js
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content"+".sticky");
```

`".content"+".sticky"` evaluates to `".content.sticky"`, which is meaning, that one element should have both classes `.content` and `.sticky`.

Try to use this:

```js
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".content + .sticky");
```

Also, the plus selector in the CSS is not commutative, so `.content + .sticky` (content element following sticky element) and `.sticky + .content` (sticky element following content element) are different selectors. Make sure that you are using the same selector in the CSS and in the JS.

---

However, if you want to match a single element, that have both classes `.content` and `.sticky`, than your error is in the CSS.

In this case you need to change `.sticky + .content { ... }` to `.sticky.content { ... }`

---

Also this line is invalid:

```js
myElements[i].style.sticky = -150 +"px";;
```

There is no `sticky` property in the CSS3.

Maybe you want to add a `sticky` class to the element? This can be done like this:

```js
myElements[i].classList.add('sticky');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a literal `+` instead of concatenating strings:

```
.content + .sticky
```

That selects siblings though - you may just want a simple multi-class selector string, in which case you'd use a comma.

```
.content, .sticky
```